# return conflicts in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, return

I am writing a function to solve the [word search problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search/). However, I run into a predicament of how to correctly get return value from my dfs recursive function. Here is the problem: if I use the keyword `return` in the last line of the code, it prematurely ends `for direction in [[0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0]]` loop once the return is hit. However, if I remove the `return` in the last line, the recursive function will work fines, but it will never return `True` from 
`if len(word)==0:print("TRUE") return True` statement even when the statement is met. I basically understand that once the program hits `return` it will ignore all codes after it. Could you please explain how to get out of this trap?

```
def dfs(cur, board, word):
    board[cur[0]][cur[1]] = None
    print(cur, board, word)
    if len(word)==0:
        print("TRUE")
        return True   

    for direction in [[0,1],[0,-1],[1,0],[-1,0]]:
        Doard = copy.deepcopy(board)
        x = cur[0]+ direction[0]
        y = cur[1]+ direction[1]
        if x>len(board)-1 or x<0 or y>len(board[0])-1 or y<0:
            continue
        if Doard[x][y] == word[0]:
            Doard[x][y] = None
            return dfs([x,y], Doard, word[1:])  # Problematic RETURN keyword here
```

Comment: You should use conditional return. Basically, just wrap it with `if`. If you find the right solution, then return True. Otherwise, do not return. That will allow the rest of for-loop iterations to actually take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice that @kszl is giving you is good, check the result of the recursive call and only return if it's `True`, otherwise let the loop play out and return `False` at the end of your function.

You left off your function that starts the `dfs()` search only at points in the board where the first letter of the `word` is found -- I've recreated that.  Issues I see with your code: you `deepcopy()` the board too early, many of your copies never get used; your use of `x` and `y` are confusing, if not inverted, I switched to `row` and `column` below; you replace letters with `None` in two places in `dfs()` but should only do it in one.

My rework of your code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

board = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'E'],
    ['S', 'F', 'C', 'S'],
    ['A', 'D', 'E', 'E'],
]

def dfs(current, board, word):
    if not word:
        return True

    current_row, current_column = current
    rows, columns = len(board), len(board[0])
    first, rest = word[0], word[1:]

    for r, c in [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]:
        row = current_row + r
        column = current_column + c

        if not (0 <= row < rows and 0 <= column < columns):
            continue

        if board[row][column] == first:
            clone = deepcopy(board)
            clone[row][column] = None

            if dfs((row, column), clone, rest):
                return True

    return False

def search_starting_letter(board, word):
    rows, columns = len(board), len(board[0])

    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            if board[row][column] == word[0]:
                clone = deepcopy(board)
                clone[row][column] = None

                if dfs((row, column), clone, word[1:]):
                    return True

    return False

word = "ABCCED"

print(search_starting_letter(board, word))
```

Comment: Thank you @cdlane very much. I am a non-CS major, but try to make it into the field. Thanks for pointing out the inappropriate usage in my original code. By knowing what I had done wrong, the right answer is much clearer.